# How to render svg elements with crisp edges while still keeping anti-aliasing?

Tags: html, svg

**Is there a way to render svg elements with crisp edges while still keeping anti-aliasing?**

I'm creating a browser-based tool that works in modern browsers.

Playing around with the [shape-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) attribute doesn't give me the results I'm looking for.

I want my elements to have nice **anti-aliasing so that the paths look smooth** like below with `shape-rendering: auto`:

[image]

But I also want elements that don't require anti-aliasing, like the **start box to look sharp and crisp**, such as when rendered with `shape-rendering: crispEdges`:

[image]

Is this possible? Am I looking to have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: Are users allowed to zoom and pan arbitrarily? Or can you lock certain SVG world units to screen pixels?

Comment: @Phrogz: Arbitrary Zoom and pan.

Comment: **TL;DR:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Perhaps you set shape-rendering property for root svg element.
You should set shape-rendering property for each shape elements, like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="150" height="20" shape-rendering="crispEdges" 
        fill="none" stroke="black"/>
    <path d="M80,30l100,100" shape-rendering="optimizeQuality" 
        stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Well, do I feel stupid now. I was under the incorrect impression that the `shape-rendering` property was only allowed on the root svg element. Need to read the docs (that I linked to) better... Thanks @defghi1977

Comment: I'm still getting serious problems when zooming in and out with `crispEdges`. when the scale is small, some edges of my rectangles disappear and reappear at a different zoom level. That's another question though.

Comment: If you ignore IE, try vector-effect property. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/painting.html#NonScalingStroke Or Try switch shape-rendering from crispEdges to optimizeQuality by javascript or mediaquery.

Comment: The only allowed values for the `shape-rendering` attribute are: `auto | optimizeSpeed | crispEdges | geometricPrecision`. Only the `color-rendering` property allows `optimizeQuality`.

Comment: @defghi1977 is shape-rendering="crispEdges" is supported in IE 11?

Comment: @vallis [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/image-rendering) accepts the `optimizeQuality` attribute as well.

Comment: Firefox doesn't seem to [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) `optimizeQuality`

Answer (score 30):

If you want your boxes to appear sharp without any blurring due to antialiasing, and without using crispEdges mode, make sure the line edges are on pixel boundaries.  So, for example, if your lines are an odd number of pixels wide, give them coordinates that are at 0.5 of a pixel.

```
<rect x="10.5" y="10.5" width="150" height="20" 
    stroke-width="1px" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
```

And on the boundary if the stroke width is even.

```
<rect x="10" y="10" width="150" height="20" 
    stroke-width="2px" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
```

Of course, this only really works if your SVG is being rendered at 1:1. That is, it's not being rescaled by the browser.  And only for lines that are horizontal and vertical.

Comment: That's a good tip. I never thought about doing something like that

Answer (score 13):

[I'm posting this as an answer rather than a comment, because I want to post a picture.  Otherwise, this is a comment on the [useful post by @defghi1977](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22165796/279844) .  +1 to him, by the way.]

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="150" height="20" shape-rendering="crispEdges" 
          fill="none" stroke="black" />
    <rect x="10" y="50" width="150" height="20" shape-rendering="auto" 
          fill="none" stroke="black" />
    <path d="M40,30l100,100" shape-rendering="crispEdges" 
          stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />
    <path d="M80,30l100,100" shape-rendering="auto" 
          stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
```

Produced

[image]

This was rendered by Firefox 38.0.5 .
In Internet Explorer 11, both `shape-rendering` setting produces the same result with anti-aliasing and not crisp.

Comment: No such thing as optimizeQuality: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty

Comment: @RobertLongson  Fixed it.  Thank you for the heads-up and for the link.

Comment: For 0, 90 and 45 dregree angles (your examples), cripsEdges looks good but it looks bad for other angles and curves.