# SVG shape rendering dots appears

Tags: svg

I'm making SVG effects by combining 2 identical photos with alternate slits. When you look closely, there are dotted lines 45 degree across the whole images. Referencing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161624/how-to-render-svg-elements-with-crisp-edges-while-still-keeping-anti-aliasing), I already tried the option `shape-rendering="optimizeQuality"`, `shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"` and `shape-rendering="auto"` on `<polygon>` tags, but the dots still appears.

How do I remove the tiny dots?

Partial HTML codes (full code is too long to post here, see JSFiddle below for full CSS, JS and HTML codes):

```
<div class="image_wrapper">
    <svg id="svg-1" class="clip-svg">
        <image class="svg-image" xlink:href="http://cdn.idigitaltimes.com/sites/idigitaltimes.com/files/styles/image_embed/public/2016/09/28/pen-pineapple-apple-pen-meaning-lyrics-ppap-piko-taro-youtube-video-watch-how-do_1.jpg" width="640" height="360" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="image_wrapper2">
    <svg id="svg-2" class="clip-svg">
        <image class="svg-image" xlink:href="http://cdn.idigitaltimes.com/sites/idigitaltimes.com/files/styles/image_embed/public/2016/09/28/pen-pineapple-apple-pen-meaning-lyrics-ppap-piko-taro-youtube-video-watch-how-do_1.jpg" width="640" height="360" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

JSFiddle demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/1a3bckcp/3/)

[image: dots appear]

Comment: why downvote without reasons?

Comment: images use image-rendering, not shape-rendering

Comment: Thanks Robert, but if you read my JSFiddle, I applied `shape-rendering` to `<polygon>` instead of image. Should I add `image-rendering` to the `<image>` tag? Which value should I use?

Comment: I have no access to jsfiddle from my current location. Please put everything that is necessary to answer the question in the question itself.

Comment: Robert, the original codes have thousands of lines, and most of them are just polygon coordinates. Too long to post in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dots are caused by anti-aliasing of the polygons that you are using for the diagonal slit clipping paths.

IMO there isn't any way to prevent that.  It may or may not get better if you turn anti-aliasing off with `shape-rendering="optimizeSpeed". And even if that works on one browser, it may not work on other ones.

My suggestion is to just have a complete ("un-slitted") version of the image on top. Make it invisible initially, then show it once the animation has finished.

Comment: Confirmed your answer with Cross Browser Testing. Even with `optimizeSpeed`, most browsers still have the diagonal slit clipping paths. Only Firefox and Mac Chrome are perfect. Wonder if it's related to display card drivers.