# Sharp edges SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, gauge

[image]Recently I made an SVG-gauge but the border looks not crisp and clear. It is little blurry. how to correct this? I tried a lot but I can't achieve it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/TIgs0DZdWmROxWacIJlj?p=preview

```
Html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="gauge0" class="gauge-container two pointer text-black active" " ng-click="identifierMenu(key) ">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000 " class="gauge "><path class="dial " fill="transparent" stroke="#eee " stroke-width="20 " d="M 100 500 A 400 400 0 0 1 900 500 "></path><text class="value-text " x="500 " y="550 " font-size="700% " font-family="sans-serif
  " font-weight="bold " text-anchor="middle "></text><path class="value " fill="transparent " stroke="#666 " stroke-width="25 " d="M 100 500 A 400 400 0 0 1 616.114 117.224 "></path></svg></a>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Styles go here */

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gauge-container {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 152px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gauge-container.two {}

.gauge-container.two > .gauge > .dial {
  stroke: #FF634D;
  stroke-width: 75;
}

.gauge-container.two > .gauge > .value {
  stroke: #00a99d;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-width: 75;
}
```

Comment: I would suspect this is due to curves trying to place colour between screen pixels (like when you try to draw a diagonal line), you end up with your graphics trying to anti-alias (smooth) the edges to make them look less "jagged". Have a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22165796/648350

Comment: I saw that @haxxxton. I can't figure out . whatever I try it look same, can u please update my plunker

Comment: shape-rendering="crispEdges" will give you sharp edges.

Comment: I tried that but it makes more bad

Comment: What browser/platform are you testing on? Can you share sa screenshot? It looks perfectly crisp on iOS Safari...

Comment: I am using Windows , Chrome.@jcaron

Comment: I have attached with the question @jcaron. Look at the borders, it is little bluury.

Comment: @SibiRaj well do you want sharp edges or not?

Comment: I just want a smooth curve borders @RobertLongson

Comment: That's what you get by default. You can have smooth (which looks a little blurry because it's antialiasing), or sharp which looks blocky. Take your pick but there's only two choices unless you get a higher res monitor/graphics card.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson..

Comment: Yes, the screenshot you posted just shows antialiasing. The blurry effect is just due to the low resolution of your screen. Check it out on a higher-resolution screen ("Retina" / "HiDPI"...), and it'll be perfectly sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the green arc is overlapping the red one.

This causes some red color in the antialiased border of the green arc, which makes it look bad:

[image]

For a quick test, make the red arc smaller, so the borders do not overlap:

[image]

The solution is to make sure the arcs do not overlap.

Zoomed out:

[image]