# svg icon + css zoom = bluriness

Tags: css, svg

I have svg icons, divs with svg background image.
When using css zoom (on document) icons get blurry.
This is how it looks (enlarged in image editing app)

[image]

I tried making it `img` element with different `image-rendering` properties, nothing helps

Is there any way to improve quality when document is zoomed?

**EDIT:**
class for my icons is (set in css file):

```
.fav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

In JavaScript I'm setting background image (based on other data):

```
favIco.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/icon.svg)';
```

CSS zoom is applied to one of the parents in hierarchy:

```
root.style.zoom = zoom + '%';
```

Comment: How do you intend to render, with perfect accuracy, something that is 2.6 pixels high?

Comment: I don't know...that's why I'm asking here

Answer (score 2):

If you scale something that is 2px high by 130%, you are going to get something that is 2.6px high. The browser will render that as two black pixels and one 60% grey pixel. That's called anti-aliasing.

The best you can do is to open the SVG file and add `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to the element or elements that you want to disable antialiasing on.

See: [How to render svg elements with crisp edges while still keeping anti-aliasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161624/how-to-render-svg-elements-with-crisp-edges-while-still-keeping-anti-aliasing)

But rather than improving quality, you may find that you get other artifacts that are even more undesirable to you than the antialiasing.

Comment: I was hoping that there is some method for SVG's that will adopt them to nearest pixel grid (at least it should)..you are right, `crispEdges` creates even worst artifacts

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing any actual code. But this demonstrates it's not impossible to have a few bars that stay crisp no matter how far you zoom in. Is there some code you can share in a snippet?

```css
i {
  zoom: 5000%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: you added huge zoom, and that masked blureiness... this is how it looks on **145% zoom** https://image.prntscr.com/image/Vc4utiLOTAi3cXd7Vjh-Pg.png