# SVG circle gradient progress has a small white border between each path

Tags: animation, svg, gradient

I have this codepen:
https://s.codepen.io/cabplanalp/debug/EJWGzE

The first item has the code help I found to get rid of the small white border between the paths but the antialias code is not working on the path:

svg tag I applied:  shape-rendering="crispEdges"

path tag I applied: shape-rendering="optimizeQuality" <-- this is not a property of Shape-rendering, so what can I use

I tried to follow this code example: [How to render svg elements with crisp edges while still keeping anti-aliasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161624/how-to-render-svg-elements-with-crisp-edges-while-still-keeping-anti-aliasing)

Please let me know how I can get that first one to look like the other two but not with that small white border between each path.

https://s.codepen.io/cabplanalp/debug/EJWGzE

```
<li data-name="" data-percent="">
        <svg viewBox="-10 -10 229 229" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
        <g fill="none" stroke-width="10" transform="translate(100,100)">
        <path d="M 0,-100 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,-50" stroke="url(#cl1)"  shape-rendering="optimizeQuality" />
        <path d="M 86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,50" stroke="url(#cl2)"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,100" stroke="url(#cl3)"/>
        <path d="M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,50" stroke="url(#cl4)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,-50" stroke="url(#cl5)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,-100" stroke="url(#cl6)"/>
        </g>
        </svg>
        <svg viewBox="-10 -10 229 229">
        <path d="M200,100 C200,44.771525 155.228475,0 100,0 C44.771525,0 0,44.771525 0,100 C0,155.228475 44.771525,200 100,200 C155.228475,200 200,155.228475 200,100 Z" stroke-dashoffset="629"></path>
        </svg>
    </li>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

Comment: Overlap the paths slightly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need six gradients?  It looks to me like one would be enough.  Then your problems with cracks disappear.

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 229 229">
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="grad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0.3" y1="0" x2="0.7" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#3170B7" />
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#00A8FF" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00E6A2" />
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g fill="none" stroke-width="10" transform="translate(100,100)">
  <circle x="0" y="0" r="100" stroke="url(#grad)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: **THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!** I was having such a hard time with this, i am novice to SVGs and animations and there is so many parameters this completely helped solved this, another quick question do you know where in my code controls the speed of the animation that fills, I cannot really pin-point it

Comment: It's the `10s` (10 seconds) in `animation: load 10s`