# How are images scaled without aliasing in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have tried both high quality png files and SVG files through the svg package, but no matter what when I scale the image smaller, heavy aliasing appears on the image.

How do professional apps keep their images high quality and vector like when scaled down?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161624/how-to-render-svg-elements-with-crisp-edges-while-still-keeping-anti-aliasing

Answer (score 1):

Now Flutter doesn't clip  by deafult. There are a few exceptions tho, like ClipRect.
You need to explicitly set `clipBehavior` in widgets constructions.
This change has appeared due to performance issues.

Add `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias` if you need anti-aliased clipping.

Add `clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer` if you want to get the result before these changes were made. Please note that it's costly in performance.

Answer (score 0):

User filter quality

```
Image(
                  width: 400,
                  height: 200,
                  filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'assets/images/logo.png',
                  ),
                ),
```